# What is the best way to find the derivative of binomials to a power? ((x+x^{-1})^3)'

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I came to a problem on my homework and I want to know the best way to solve it.  We are doing derivatives in Calculus.  I've got the following:

$$H(x)=(x+x^{-1})^3$$

$$H'(x)=((x+x^{-1})^3)'$$

I am trying to avoid using the product theorem to do them 2 at a time, because that just sounds nasty.

I am trying something like this:

$$((x+x^{-1})^3)' = ((3x+3x^{-1})^2)'$$

But it feels like I'm doing something wrong..  Do I do the product theorem from here?

Comment: Do you know about the chain rule?

Comment: What you have written isn't valid. You can't distribute a power across a sum, let alone do so as a multiplier. The comment of @T.Bongers will get you where you need to go...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^3$ and $g(x)=x+x^{-1}$. Therefore we see that
$$f(g(x))=(x+x^{-1})^3.$$ We use the chain rule, which you can read about [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule):
$$
\begin{align} \frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))&=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x) \\
&=3(g(x))^2\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right) \\
&=3(x+x^{-1})^2\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right). \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Let $h(x)=f(g(x))$, then $h'(x)=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x).$

Comment: Right, I think you're missing a parenthesis, in the answer.  Makes sense though.  Thanks.

Comment: My bad. Fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use the product rule.

The derivative of a function $u^n$ is $$(u^n)' = n*u^{n-1}*(u')$$

So your function is $$(x+ x^{-1})^3$$.

Now, taking the derivative: $$3*(x+x^{-1})^2*(1 - \frac{1}{x^2})$$